# How to pinch to zoom a view without making the view bigger?

Tags: ios, swift, multi-touch

This is what I currently have:

```
func handlePinching(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale));
    recognizer.scale = 1.0;
}
```

Using `self.view.transform` for that also makes it bigger. I want to make it zoom "internally" (I really don't know how to explain it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not 100% sure to understand the question but I guess I get it.

For example you want to zoom on an image without zooming the other element of the UI (NavBar, Buttons, ...) right?

So I guess in you're example you're in a viewController, which means, when you change the scale of `self.view` you'll zoom everything. You have to apply the scale on the specific view that you want to zoom in.

In the example below, to zoom on the image, the image is inside of an UIImageView, and this imageView is subView of `self.view`. And you will just apply a transform on this imageView.

Moreover I think you get a little bit confused on how to zoom, considering the view you want to zoom is `imageView` you just need to do

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale,recognizer.scale)
```

I hope this answer your question, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: I wanted to zoom in the needed view without making it get bigger than the given layer size. So, I ended up just adding the view inside a scroll view, which already has support for zoom